# Is it possible to create a system for 'shared wallets' on top of bitcoin?

Tags: wallet, client, alternatives, altcoin

Is it possible to build a system on top of bitcoin, where:

- Random people will deposit money in a wallet X.
- Nobody has access to that wallet.
- After a few months, those users will vote in other wallets for the money in wallet X to go.
- The money in wallet X is distributed between those wallets.

Is it possible on top of bitcoin, or would it need the design of a new system?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called a [Distributed Contract](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts) or a [Smart Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract).

Projects like [Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/) are aiming to make this much more of a reality. Currently they're a bit of a pain to write.